# Did I buy the wrong SBR rails? They don't seem to attach or align

Tags: cnc, tools

I have bought some SBR12 rails and bearing blocks in an attempt to make a fancy flatenning jig for my router.

I haven't been able to see 100% everything that other people have done on the YouTubes due to camera angles etc, but I went ahead and bought some to fit the table I currently have.

The idea is to have two rails attached atop another 2 rails perpendicularly as to act as an X and a Y axis to move the router across the workpiece easily.

The issue I have found now the rails have arrived is that the holes in the rails designed for fixing them to a tabletop etc don't align fully with the threaded holes in the tops of the bearing blocks...

Is this something that is normal, or was I just naive to the idea that they would fit perfectly? Also, is there something you can suggest I do to attach these securely?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you check the size of bearing block so the hole centre-line would match the rail holes distance from the edges?

Comment: You needed to check the dimensioned drawings on the datasheets and, at least, make some sketches to check. Usually the CAD models are available and you can create a 3D assembly model using something like OnShape to check things out.

Comment: @Transistor that would have been a good idea, except this was an amazon reseller and they didn't have too much info on there to begin with - I naively assumed that they were all the same? Oops. At least there's returns ;-)

Comment: Would you by chance know of any suitable UK retailers of these SBR rails blocks?